# When are Hadoop counters persisted?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have a simple MapReduce job that uses Hadoop Counters to count unique `Ids` in the *reduce* phase of my job.

Are counter changes persisted immediately when I do an increment from Java code, or only after successful execution of a task?

The reason I'm wondering is to find out if I should disable speculative execution in the job, as this could cause double counting unless counter changes only happen after successful execution of a task. And even then, could there be race conditions if identical tasks succeed around the same time?

Comment: I strongly doubt that Hadoop does not handle correctly speculative execution together with counters. Both are common features, so I assume that they just work fine. Why do you suspect any bugs?

Comment: I'm not implying this is a bug.  I just don't have deep understanding of this topic.  Since counters feel like a 'side effect' it reasons that they could be persisted instantly.